Azure Function Trigger Not Processing Images in PDFs Correctly
I'm encountering an issue with my Azure Function trigger, which processes files uploaded to Azure Blob Storage and indexes them into Azure Cognitive Search. The function works perfectly for most file types (e.g., standalone images, DOCX, CSV), but it fails to correctly process images embedded within PDFs.
Here's a brief overview of my setup:
The Azure Function is triggered by an Event Grid event when a blob is created or deleted in Azure Blob Storage.
The function retrieves the blob's metadata, extracts its content based on the file type, and then uploads the content to Azure Cognitive Search.
While standalone images, DOCX files, and other document types are processed and indexed correctly, the function fails to process images within PDFs.
I have tested the indexer manually through the Azure portal, and it works as expected for images in PDFs. However, when triggered automatically by the Azure Function, the images in PDFs are not processed correctly.
Here is the main part of my trigger code:
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const { SearchClient, AzureKeyCredential } = require('@azure/search-documents');
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');
const mammoth = require('mammoth');
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const configPath = path.join(__dirname, 'config.json');
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'utf8'));
const csvParser = require('csv-parser');

const accountName = config.blobAccountName;
const accountKey = config.blobAccountKey;
const containerName = config.blobContainerName;
const searchServiceName = config.searchServiceName;
const indexName = config.searchIndexName;
const apiKey = config.searchApiKey;

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)
);

const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

const searchClient = new SearchClient(
  `https://${searchServiceName}.search.windows.net/`,
  indexName,
  new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey)
);

async function indexBlob(blobName) {
  try {
    console.log(`Indexing blob: ${blobName}`);
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
    const downloadResponse = await blobClient.download();
    const encodedName = Buffer.from(blobName).toString('base64');
    console.log(`encodedName: ${encodedName}`);

    const properties = await blobClient.getProperties();
    console.log(`properties:`, properties);
    let contentType = properties.contentType || '';

    const metadata = properties.metadata || {};
    console.log(`metadata: ${metadata}`);
    const uniqueId = properties.metadata.uniqueId;
    console.log(`uniqueId: ${uniqueId}`);

    console.log("content type: ", contentType);

    if (contentType === 'application/octet-stream') {
      const extension = path.extname(blobName).toLowerCase();
      switch (extension) {
        case '.pdf':
          contentType = 'application/pdf';
          break;
        case '.txt':
          contentType = 'text/plain';
          break;
        case '.docx':
          contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
          break;
        case '.xlsx':
          contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
          break;
        case '.csv':
          contentType = 'text/csv';
          break;
        default:
          if (imageExtensions.includes(extension)) {
            contentType = 'image/*';
          } else {
            console.log(`Unsupported file extension: ${extension}`);
            return;
          }
          break;
      }
    }

    let blobContent = '';
    if (contentType === 'application/pdf') {
      const pdfBuffer = await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);
      const pdfData = await pdf(pdfBuffer);
      blobContent = pdfData.text;
    } else if (contentType === 'text/plain') {
      blobContent = await streamToString(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);
    } else if (contentType === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
      const docxBuffer = await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);
      const result = await mammoth.extractRawText({ buffer: docxBuffer });
      blobContent = result.value;
    } else if (contentType === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet') {
      const excelBuffer = await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);
      const workbook = xlsx.read(excelBuffer, { type: 'buffer' });
      let excelText = '';
      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
        const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
        excelText += xlsx.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet) + '\n';
      });
      blobContent = excelText;
    } else if (contentType === 'text/csv') {
      const csvBuffer = await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);
      blobContent = await csvToString(csvBuffer);
    } else if (contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
      blobContent = ''; // Let OCR handle image processing
    } else {
      console.log(`Unsupported content type: ${contentType}`);
      return;
    }

    const document = {
      id: encodedName,
      content: blobContent,
      metadata_storage_content_type: properties.contentType || null,
      metadata_storage_size: properties.contentLength || null,
      metadata_storage_last_modified: properties.lastModified ? new Date(properties.lastModified).toISOString() : null,
      metadata_storage_content_md5: properties.contentMD5 ? Buffer.from(properties.contentMD5).toString('base64') : null,
      metadata_storage_name: blobName,
      metadata_storage_path: blobClient.url,
      metadata_storage_file_extension: path.extname(blobName),
      metadata_content_type: properties.contentType || null,
      metadata_language: null,
      metadata_author: null,
      metadata_creation_date: properties.creationTime ? new Date(properties.creationTime).toISOString() : null,
    };

    await searchClient.uploadDocuments([document]);
    console.log(`Document "${document.id}" has been indexed`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error indexing document:`, error);
    if (error.name === 'RestError') {
      console.error(`RestError message:`, error.message);
      console.error(`RestError details:`, error.response && error.response.body);
    }
  }
}

app.eventGrid('process-event-grid', {
  handler: async (context, eventGridEvent) => {
    try {
      console.log(`Event received: ${JSON.stringify(eventGridEvent)}`);
      const blobUrl = eventGridEvent.data.url;
      const blobapi = eventGridEvent.data.api;
      const blobName = blobUrl.substring(blobUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      if (blobapi === 'PutBlob') {
        await indexBlob(blobName);
      } else if (blobapi === 'DeleteBlob') {
        await deleteDocument(blobName);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error processing event: ${error}`, eventGridEvent);
    }
  }
});

async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
      chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
    });
    readableStream.on("end", () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });
    readableStream.on("error", reject);
  });
}

async function streamToString(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
      chunks.push(data.toString());
    });
    readableStream.on("end", () => {
      resolve(chunks.join(''));
    });
    readableStream.on("error", reject);
  });
}

async function csvToString(buffer) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const results = [];
    const readableStream = bufferToStream(buffer);
    readableStream
      .pipe(csvParser())
      .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
      .on('end', () => {
        const csvString = results.map(row => Object.values(row).join(',')).join('\n');
        resolve(csvString);
      })
      .on('error', reject);
  });
}

function bufferToStream(buffer) {
  const stream = new require('stream').Readable();
  stream.push(buffer);
  stream.push(null);
  return stream;
}

async function deleteDocument(blobName) {
  try {
    console.log(`Deleting document: ${blobName}`);
    const encodedName = Buffer.from(blobName).toString('base64');
    console.log(`encodedName: ${encodedName}`);
    await searchClient.deleteDocuments([{ id: encodedName }]);
    console.log(`Document "${encodedName}" has been deleted from the index`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error deleting document:`, error);
    if (error.name === 'RestError') {
      console.error(`RestError message:`, error.message);
      console.error(`RestError details:`, error.response && error.response.body);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = app;



Image processing is indexer-driven, which means that the raw inputs must be in a  supported data source.

Image analysis supports JPEG, PNG, GIF, and BMP
OCR supports JPEG, PNG, BMP, and TIF

Images are either standalone binary files or embedded in documents (PDF, RTF, and Microsoft application files). A maximum of 1000 images can be extracted from a given document.

If original images are embedded in PDF or application files like PPTX or DOCX, you'll need to add a Text Merge skill if you want image output and text output together

Thank you for the suggestion to add the Text Merge skill. I have ensured that my skillset includes both the Text Merge skill and OCR skill, and it works when tested manually through the Azure portal. However, my main challenge is modifying my Azure Function code (async function indexBlob) to handle PDFs that include images correctly. I need guidance on: Extracting both text and images from a PDF within the Azure Function. Running OCR on the extracted images. Merging the text extracted from the PDF and the OCR results from the images.

To resolve the error of  fails to process images with PDFs we add skill of  Text Merge skill to existing skill set.


The Image processing is indexer-driven, which means that the raw inputs must be in a supported data source.
Image analysis supports JPEG, PNG, GIF, and BMP - OCR supports JPEG, PNG, BMP, and TIF Images are either standalone binary files or embedded in documents (PDF, RTF, and Microsoft application files). A maximum of 1000 images can be extracted from a given document.
If original images are embedded in PDF or application files like PPTX or DOCX, you'll need to add a Text Merge skill if you want image output and text output together


I refered this MSDOC to add text Merge cognitive skill  to Azure AI Search.
The below is my skillset  in  Azure Cognitive Search (azureblob-skillset) that combines skills for text merging, OCR (Optical Character Recognition), and image analysis.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://AzureSearchServiceName.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCA17590BC319B\"",
  "name": "azureblob-skillset",
  "description": "Skillset created from the portal. skillsetName: azureblob-skillset; contentField: merged_content; enrichmentGranularity: document; knowledgeStoreStorageAccount: ;",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.MergeSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": null,
      "context": "/document",
      "insertPreTag": " ",
      "insertPostTag": " ",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        },
        {
          "name": "itemsToInsert",
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/text"
        },
        {
          "name": "offsets",
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/contentOffset"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "mergedText",
          "targetName": "merged_content"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.OcrSkill",
      "name": "#2",
      "description": null,
      "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
      "textExtractionAlgorithm": null,
      "lineEnding": "Space",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "detectOrientation": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "image",
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "targetName": "text"
        },
        {
          "name": "layoutText",
          "targetName": "layoutText"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.ImageAnalysisSkill",
      "name": "#3",
      "description": null,
      "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "visualFeatures": [
        "tags",
        "description"
      ],
      "details": [],
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "image",
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "tags",
          "targetName": "imageTags"
        },
        {
          "name": "description",
          "targetName": "imageCaption"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": null,
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}



After creating  and deploying  the azure function to azure . Connect the azure function  to the events with Event Subscription  In Endpoint as show in the below images by selecting filters of event types.

The Event grid Function responds/triggers to the events of azure Storage action selected in Filter to Event Type.

Azure Function Output:
Azure AI Search Output:



Refer to git to add skillset Operations Using JavaScript . To  Set up a schedule which keeps your index up to date (or) Update the data from source to azure ai search add Schedule.In azure ai search make sure OCR is enabled.


Thank you for the suggestion to add the Text Merge skill. I have ensured that my skillset includes both the Text Merge skill and OCR skill, and it works when tested manually through the Azure portal. However, my main challenge is modifying my Azure Function code (async function indexBlob) to handle PDFs that include images correctly.
I need guidance on:
Extracting both text and images from a PDF within the Azure Function.
Running OCR on the extracted images.
Merging the text extracted from the PDF and the OCR results from the images.

Document Extraction cognitive skill extracts text and images. Refer to this MSDOC
